# How to select a particular element in g elements and change its status in D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to understand how to select an element within the SVG Group element in D3.js. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var circleData = [
 { "cx": 20, "cy": 20, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
 { "cx": 70, "cy": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple" }];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                     .attr("width",200)
                     .attr("height",200);

var circleGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

//Add a group to hold the circles
var circleGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

//Add circles to the circleGroup
var circles = circleGroup.selectAll("circle")
                         .data(circleData).enter().append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; });

var pickCirlces = circleGroup.selectAll("circle")
                            .data(circleData,function(d) { return d.color=="purple";}).transition().duration(1200).style("fill","black");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code creates two circles. The first one is green and the second one is purple according to the array provided above. I am trying to change the colour of the second circle from purple to black by selecting it based on its original colour which is purple.

```
var pickCirlces = circleGroup.selectAll("circle")
        .data(circleData,function(d) { return d.color =="purple"; }).transition().duration(1200).style("fill","black");
```

I can't manage to select the second circle to change its colour because both circles are grouped within g element. Could anyone please help me do this with a brief explanation. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat but one common way is to filter the data for the selection:

```
var pickCirlces = circleGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .filter(function(d) {return d.color === "purple"})
    .transition().duration(1200)
    .style("fill", "yellow")
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cajqp2y1/).

You can read more about this technique [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#user-content-filter).

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. To be honest, I can't fully understand how selections work internally. I should double my effort to understand it. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: YMW. [Here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) is a gentle introduction and one of my favorites, and [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) is a more heavy-duty one.